# CSS drawing border inside of an element when the border radius is set

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I guess the title is kind of hard to understand, so I'll explain.
I am trying to achieve this effect (from .png file):

This is half a cycle with black line inside

[image]

I couldn't create this inner line no matter how I tried.

This is what I got so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id='halfCycle'>
    <div id='halfCycleInner'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#halfCycle
{
    width: 23px;
    height: 43px;
    background-color: #383838;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px 0px #222;
}

#halfCycleInner
{
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    right:0px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 41px;
    background-color: #383838;
    border-top-right-radius: 60px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: #212121;
    border-right-style: solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ebqfk7w8/)

It's very close, but not the same.
Any idea how to make this inner line.

Comment: @cheziHoyer : You can use PSEUDO Class in css

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/7xs2ua9g/) is another way to achieve a similar effect using radial gradients. The browser support for this is relatively less (eg: IE<10 doesn't support it) and hence web-tiki's answer is still the best. Just wanted to show that it can be done this way also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element to and give it the border :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ebqfk7w8/1/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id='halfCycle'></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#halfCycle
{
    width: 23px;
    height: 43px;
    background-color: #383838;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px 0px #222;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#halfCycle:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:1px; right:1px;
    width:42px;
    height:39px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a solution i hope it will work for you.

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/v1t5q7j7/)***

```
.halfCycle{
    background: #383838;
    height: 42px;
    width: 20px;
    border:1px solid #202020;
    border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative; 
    box-shadow:5px 0px 5px 0px #222;
}   
.halfCycle:after{
    content: '';border:1px solid #383838;
    position: absolute;
    height: 44px;
    width: 21px;
    left:0;
    top:-2px;
    border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
    border-left:none;
}
```